# One to one Chat and any way to get user presence with AMQP

Tags: chat, amqp

I am interesting in this message service protocol to implement in my app one chat and one massive notification service.

But, if compare AMQP vs XMPP, the last have presence channel through roster, and one very easy way to implement one to one chat. I need one to one chat, no multichat that I know is very easy with publish/subscription message service way.

Need XMPP to do both?

Comment: Use that tool you are familiar with. AMQP is not a silver bullet, same as XMPP. What you described can be done in numerous way, so, just do it (c)

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep track of user presence with a plugin of RabbitMQ called "presence exchange", while easily implementing one-to-one chat with RabbitMQ .

Here is a link about a document http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/10/19/exchange-to-exchange-bindings/    -- example-2

Here is the plugin https://github.com/tonyg/presence-exchange